# jQuery tour plugin issues

Tags: jquery-plugins

I am trying to install a jQuery site tour, using the following tutorial http://tympanus.net/Development/WebsiteTour/

I think I installed everything correctly, and the navigation box seems to work ok, but only a couple of the tooltips show, and the tour doesn't seem to want to scroll down to my footer.

In Firebug, I'm getting the following error: `$elem.offset() is null
[Break On This Error] var e_l = $elem.offset().left;`

This is the site address: http://www.aeringuy.com/dev/

Can anyone point me in the right direction for trouble shooting this?

Thanks,

Yukon

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The files 'ChunkFive_400.font.js' and 'pos-handle40.png' are missing and are returning the 'This Site is Under Construction' page with incorrect HTTP Status Code (200 OK) and I think that's causing the problem. Blame the 'Maintenance Mode Plugin' author, either disable it or fix those missing files.

Comment: Thanks SalmanAbbas007! I think I fixed that, but it didn't help. It seems to be working just fine on their demo: http://tympanus.net/Development Any other ideas where to look?